# Multiple DNS servers for website failover

Tags: domain-name-system, failover

I know this is a bad "solution", if its even one, but due to the circumstances I think it fits.

If Server A runs ns1.example.com and Server 2 runs ns2.example.com and both are hosting an exact duplicate of a website but each have www.example.com DNS A records pointing to themselves. Will this work as a cheap/fast (to setup) failover solution in case server A suddenly fails?

The way I see it, a downtime of 30min-1hr is of no real concern so DNS TTL can be adjusted around that time.

Comment: What are you asking, will it cover a DNS failure or a website failure?

Comment: website failure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will this work as a cheap/fast (to setup) failover solution

Not really.

DNS Round Robin is not really a failover or HA solution. It's more of a load balancing solution. If one of the servers fail, about half the requests to your website **may** also fail until the record of the offline server is first removed from the DNS server and then you have to wait for the TTL value to expire after it is removed and wait for the end systems to clear it out of their cache.

edit: If you are looking to setup both NS servers to serve the same zone with different records, that is likely a non-starter.

Comment: yeah was about to comment on Nick's post about that, now that I'm looking into it you are right

Comment: If these are external sites, there are fairly inexpensive providers that can do DNS record failover where they update the A record with a very short TTL to a different address when they detect a failure on one of the servers. It's not load balanced, but it would be straight failover. Amazon ROute 53 would be about $2/month for this, DNSMadeEasy would be $30/year + $2/month for the failover add-on (disclaimer: prices might increase depending on the number or queries/zones/etc and is subject to change :)

Answer (score 0):

Round robin DNS usually requires that both servers offer up both A records, as having multiple authoritative DNS servers which will present different zones to a single client is a no go, at the very least from an administrative standpoint, and very probably from an RFC standpoint.